# Permission Denied In Reading the Data from Firebase Realtime Database via Client (Node SDK)

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to access the `subscription_id` value once from Firebase Realtime DB.
The data structure is as follows:

```
/customers/id/subscription_id
```

On client side I am doing:

```
import app from "firebase/app"
app.initializeApp(config)

app.database().ref(`customers/${sid}/subscription_id`).once('value')
.then(dataSnapshot => {
  console.log(dataSnapshot.val())
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

And on Firebase Back-end, I'm setting database rules as follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('users/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('users/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])"
      },
      ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])",
      ".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])"
    },
  }
}
```

By the away, I create a user with custom `uid` using `admin.creataUser()` in cloud function. Is it owing to this custom id that I'm getting access denied or there is something wrong with rules?

Comment: Your rules give access to `/users`. But your code tries to read from `customers`. You probably want both of them to refer to the same node names.

Answer (score 0):

My bad... My sleepy brain was going all numb all night. Laughing at my silliness here!

Yes, one needs to set the correct database refs to be accessed and overwrite in rules as pointed out by Frank in a comment.

So all working well now with the following corrected rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "customers": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('customers/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('customers/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])"
      },
      ".read": "root.child('customers/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])",
      ".write": "root.child('customers/'+auth.uid).child('roles').hasChildren(['ADMIN'])"
    },
  }
}
```